# What is the best practice way to handle arithmetic exception in Mathematica

Tags: programming, error-tracking, arithmetic

What is/are common way/s to handle what would be ArithmeticExceptions in Java in Mathematica/ Wolfram Language? The ugly code is the If...Continues in the innermost For Loop. How should I address this with the Wolfram Language programming paradigm?

```
c=0;
best={0,{}};
operators={Plus,Subtract,Times,Divide};
numbersets=Subsets[{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},{4}];
For[i=1,i<= Length[numbersets],i++,
 results=Table[False,9^4];
 currentSet=numbersets[[i]];
 permutations=Permutations[currentSet];
  For[j=1,j<= Length[permutations],j++,
   For[op1=1,op1<= Length[operators],op1++,
    For[op2=1,op2<= Length[operators],op2++,
     For[op3=1,op3<= Length[operators],op3++,
      c=c+1;
      If[operators[[op1]]==Divide && permutations[[j]][[2]]==0,Continue[]];
      If[operators[[op2]]==Divide && permutations[[j]][[3]]==0,Continue[]];
      If[operators[[op3]]==Divide && permutations[[j]][[4]]==0,Continue[]];
      r=operators[[op1]][permutations[[j]][[1]],permutations[[j]][[2]]];
      r=operators[[op2]][r,permutations[[j]][[3]]];
      r=operators[[op3]][r,permutations[[j]][[4]]];
      If[r>0 && IntegerQ[r],results[[r]]=True;]
     ];
    ]
   ]
  ]
 If[FirstPosition[results,False][[1]]-1>best[[1]],
  best={FirstPosition[results,False][[1]]-1,currentSet};
  Print[{FirstPosition[results,False]-1,currentSet}];
 ]
]
```

and yes it is Eul3r again and it does not work, but that is irrelevant to the question...

Comment: Simplest thing to do is to remove the If statements entirely and to add `// Quiet` after the whole thing.

Comment: `Check[]`? (In the *Mathematica* paradigm, you would at least use `Do[]` instead of `For[]` here, but also take advantage of listability/vectorization to reduce the number of loops and increase speed.  But that's a side issue.)

Comment: Which project Euler problem is it actually? Would make some things easier ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways you can make your code more idiomatic for the Wolfram language.
First thing we can do is representing operators and numbersets with strings (i'll come to the advatage of this a bit later):

```
operators = {"+", "-", "*", "/"};
numbersets = Subsets[ToString /@ Range[0, 9], {4}];
```

Then we can apply the same idea you used for `numbersets` by using `Subsets[]` to have a similar `operatorsets`

```
operatorsets = Tuples[operators, 3];
```

This replaces all of your nested loops to give us a list of all possible operator combinations.
We can now combine this with our numbersets to get all possible combinations of numbers and operators via `Outer[]`:

```
RiffleAndJoin = Composition[StringJoin, Riffle];
expressionstrings = Flatten[Outer[RiffleAndJoin, numbersets, operatorsets, 1], 1]
(* {"0+1+2+3", "0+1+2-3", ..., "6/7/8/9"} *)
```

`Outer` combines each element of `numbersets` with each element of `operatorsets`, which get than fed to a function of our choice, in this case our customly defined function `RiffleAndJoin` which takes the two lists of one character strings and riffles them, then joins them into one big string which represents the whole expression as a string. Then we call `Flatten` to get a flat list of string expressions. The reason for representing the expression as strings is, that we don't have to do the work of parsing the expression. We can just call

```
ToExpression /@ expressionstrings
(* {6, 0, 7, ..., 27/28, 1/84} *)
```

and let Mathematica do the expression parsing and evaluation!

Comment: Sorry, just saw you are also going through every permutation for each numberset, so not 100% equivalent. Maybe you still get some new ideas from my answer.